# How to pass a JavaScript variable in Rails "User.select(...)"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have two lines of code:

```
var itemname = document.getElementById("itemname"+x.toString()).value;

var test = JSON.parse('<%= raw Item.select('promCode','baseCode','monadaMe','price','fpa').where(:itemName => 'itemname' ).collect { |p| [p.promCode, p.baseCode, p.monadaMe, p.price, p.fpa] }.join("\n").gsub("\n", " ").split(" ")%>');
```

I want to pass my `var itemname` to `where(:itemName=> 'itemname')`.

Comment: JS is executed in the browser while ruby is only on the server so your query cannot depend on a rendered DOM element as it is executed before sending the file to the browser

Comment: You could send `itemname` with an AJAX request to the server and do your query in a controller, rendering JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to pass a variable from the JavaScript running on the client to Rails which is running on the server is by sending a HTTP request.

The code is running in two completely separate processes, on different machines and at different times. This applies not just to rails but any time you are generating JavaScript on the server - in any language/framework.

Your `js.erb` template is first run through ERB on your server. Which just processes it as a string buffer and evaluates any ERB tags contained. Rails then sends the result to the client which actually runs the javascript. Its thus completely impossible for rails to ever know the value of a variable derived from an element that may not even exist yet when the code is run through ERB.

If you want to populate the a select with values from your server you need to do an [AJAX request](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/rails-ajax/) to the server which either returns JSON which you use to build the elements or javacript rendered by a `js.erb` template which alters the page if you want to go further down that rabbit hole.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you use JavaScript's template literals, using the backtick?:

```
var test = JSON.parse(`<%= raw Item.select('promCode','baseCode','monadaMe','price','fpa').where(:itemName => '${itemname}' ).collect { |p| [p.promCode, p.baseCode, p.monadaMe, p.price, p.fpa] }.join("\n").gsub("\n", " ").split(" ")%>`);
```

In JavaScript, you can use backticks ("``") with `${}` just as you would use double quotes (`""`) with `#{}` in Ruby to interpolate text.

So, in JavaScript:

```
const name = 'kostasew';
const interpolated = `Hi there, ${name}!`;

console.log(interpolated); // prints 'Hi there, kostasew!
```

You can also check "Template literals (Template strings)[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)" for more information.

Comment: that working outside of the <%%> place but inside i get nil value

Comment: -1 This is fundamentially impossible since the ERB template is rendered on the server and the javascript runs on the client. Backticks are just totally irrelevant.